# SonarQube Azure AD SAML authentication

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-active-directory, sonarqube, saml

I have a SQ instance with Nginx on docker-compose, when adding SAML AUTH through Azure's AD I get following errors;

from SQ container -

> ERROR web[AXxUzLA1NnhuSmG1AAB5][c.o.s.a.SamlResponse] The response was received at http://sonarqube:9000/oauth2/callback/saml instead of https://sonarqube-hello.msappproxy.net/oauth2/callback/saml
> ERROR web[AXxUzLA1NnhuSmG1AAB5][c.o.saml2.Auth] processResponse error. invalid_response

from SQ UI -

> [image]

**while logs in Azure are indicating successful authorization**

Nginx conf -

```
  listen 80;

  client_max_body_size 100M;

  server_name sonarqube.local;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://sonarqube:9000;
  }
}


server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/server.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/server.key;
 location / {
   proxy_pass http://sonarqube:9000;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
 }
}
```

- Sonar version 9.1, no plug-ins
- SAML provider works great with other tools

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error it seems that problem is with the URL. Please re-check the Redirect URI. it should be set to "Web" in the drop down and For the URL field, you should mention authentication URL for the plugin. This URL is your main SonarQube URL with "/oauth2/callback/aad" at the end. For example, if your main URL is "https://sonarqube.example.com/", you should enter "https://sonarqube.example.com/oauth2/callback/aad".

And at the same time Set up the Server base URL to be configured with HTTPS address in Administration >>Configuration >> General >> Server base URL:
The redirect URL must have a https, a non-https address will throw errors.

[Reference](https://dfar.io/setting-up-sonarqube-in-azure-with-azure-ad-integration/)

[SonarQube Integration with Azure Active Directory](https://www.emtec.digital/think-hub/blogs/sonarqube-integration-azure-active-directory/)